# How to enable url-parameters in an MVC-framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I am currently wanting to enable $_GET parameters in my framework.

My current htaccess-file is like this, BUT it doesn't pass the ?param=param :(

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /{2,}([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?url=$0 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

When I try to go to this URL:

http://www.domain.com/test?test=test

All that gets passed is "test"

How can I make it possible to also pass $_GET-parameters?

Comment: Are you using a framework?, they have urlrewriting implemented via config files ...

Comment: This is a framework, I have developed myself, but the problem is, that I haven't had to use this before, but now I have :)

Comment: Nice,have you checked out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php ?

Comment: also, you minght find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208) relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `QSA` to your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?url=$0 [NC,L,QSA]
```

QSA stand for Query String Attach

Comment: Okay, this works - it is weird I didn't figure that out. Is there any way to disallow the "url" as a parameter in the URL? Because if it is possible to write e.g.:

http://domain.com/test?test=test&url=something

then it will return "something" to the framework routing, and that shouldn't be allowed. Any fixes to that? :)

Comment: Indeed. However given that it's part of the URL anyone could pass anything anyway, so I guess you have to do the sanitization server/framework side. You should read all the links posted in the comments ;)