# Using $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] to instantiate controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I was working with a MVC architecture in my php webapp. My architecture it's pretty simple, if I send a request to an url in this way `localhost/Dispatcher.php?class=SampleController&method=sampleMethod` this will instantiate the controller `SampleController` and invoke the method `sampleMethod` of this controller. BTW I can't use the .htaccess file. Now I want to get rid of the `Dispatcher.php`, so I thought that I could achieve that if I change the sintax of the url to something like this `localhost/SampleController.php?method=sampleMethod`. To do this I must use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to get the controller class name. All my controllers extends from `Controller`. I thought that I could instantiate the controller there, in the `Controller.php`. So, my `Controller.php` looks like this.

```
<?php
//Enable errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

//Include the controller
$include = explode("/",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])[2]; //This return MainController.php
include_once $include;

//Get the method (Like this is an example I don't care the validations)
$method = $_GET['method'];

$class = explode(".",$include)[0]; //Get rid of the *.php extention
$controller = new $class(); 
$controller->$method(); // I get Class 'MainController' not found

include_once 'View.php';
class Controller {
    public $view;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->view = new View();
    }
}

?>
```

And this is my `MainController.php`

```
<?php
include_once 'Controller.php';
include_once 'MainModel.php';
class MainController extends Controller {

    public $model;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->model = new MainModel();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->view->render('mainView','headerMain','footerMain');

    }
}

?>
```

Here I'm trying to hit this url `MainController.php?method=index`

All the names are ok, the paths are also ok. BTW if I hardcode the paths I get the same error, can be this a includes error? If I can't achieve this in the `Controller.php` there's some place where I can handle the controller instantiation without add another .php file? (I don't want get back to use the `Dispatcher.php`)

**UPDATE**
If I change the `Controller.php` in this way, works, but I get an `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class maincontroller in MainController.php on line 9`

```
<?php
include_once 'View.php';

//Enable errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

//Include the controller
$include = explode("/",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])[2]; //This return MainController.php

//Get the method (Like this is an example I don't care the validations)
$method = $_GET['method'];
$class = explode(".",$include)[0];

require($include);

$controller = new $class();
$controller->$method();


class Controller {
    public $view;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->view = new View();
    }
}
?>
```

**WORKAROUND**

I achieved what I want in this way:

MainController.php

```
<?php
//Enable errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

include_once 'Controller.php';
include_once 'MainModel.php';
class MainController extends Controller {

    public $model;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->model = new MainModel();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->view->render('mainView','headerMain','footerMain');

    }
}

require_once("Core.php");

?>
```

Controller.php

```
<?php
include_once 'View.php';

class Controller {
    public $view;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->view = new View();
    }
}
?>
```

Core.php

```
<?php
//Enable errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

//Include the controller
$include = explode("/",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])[2]; //This return MainController.php

//Get the method (Like this is an example I don't care the validations)
$method = $_GET['method'];
$class = explode(".",$include)[0];

$controller = new $class();
$controller->$method();

?>
```

But this solution still doesn't satisfice me, this isn't the object oriented solution that I want. Isn't some way of do this in the `Controller.php`?

Comment: Dumb question here: The files you are including is in same path?

Comment: There's no dumb questions buddy ;). Yup I strongly checked that.

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208).

Comment: @teresko Nice info. But what I want It's pretty simple: I want to be capable of send a request to `SampleController.php` the class there, extends from `Controller`, this class contains an method called `doRouting` that do the above stuff, how can I do that without add some extra lines outside the class definition, at the end of `SampleController.php`?. If I can achive that I think that I'll be capable of solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that in `MainController.php` you called `include_once 'Controller.php'` before the definition of your class. Then the `Controller.php` won't include `MainController.php` anymore because `include_once` noticed that it was already loaded. If you use `require` that includes `MainController.php` again, the `include_once` in `MainController.php` won't include `Controller.php` another time, declares the class and returns to `Controller.php`. When `Controller.php` is done, it will return to the original `MainController.php` and this fails to declare the class again.

You might be able to use `die()` or `exit()` at the end of `Controller.php` but I would prefer declaring a function, let's say `Process()`, that does all the stuff after initializing and call that as the last line of `MainController.php`.

**Controller.php**

```
<?php
//Enable errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

function Process()
{
    //Get the method (Like this is an example I don't care the validations)
    $method = $_GET['method'];

    $class = explode(".",$include)[0]; //Get rid of the *.php extention
    $controller = new $class(); 
    $controller->$method(); // I get Class 'MainController' not found

    include_once 'View.php';
}

class Controller {
    public $view;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->view = new View();
    }
}

?>
```

**MainController.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'Controller.php';
include_once 'MainModel.php';
class MainController extends Controller {

    public $model;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->model = new MainModel();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->view->render('mainView','headerMain','footerMain');

    }
}

Process();

?>
```

Comment: So I have to put `Process();` at the end of each controller. Is there a way to get rid of that? or put it in one place only.

Comment: Like I said - you might just add `exit()` to the end of your `Controller.php` - but that would be a little dirty solution. If it's important to you to you use the URL of the Controller but without that little `Process()` call, then that might be okay for you.