# PHP url routing with 3 parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have my framework that handle all URLs via one index.php page. If I put site.com/profile/user it will go to site.com/index.php?**url**=profile&next=user and  parameter "url" loads different pages for example /home would be index.php?url=home

Problem now is that I wont to expand my rewrite rules in htaccess file so I have one more additional parameter which would be for example site.com/profile/user/auctions and it would look like site.com/index.php?url=profile&next=user&category=auctions.

My rewrite rules are listed below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^]+)/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?$ index.php?url=$1&next=$2
```

So problem is I can't put additional "category" parameter which would be index.php?url=$1&next=$2&category=$3 , whenever I change rules  one parameter works but other dont.

Thank you for reading, and I hope it could be solved.

Comment: maybe this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?url=$1&next=$2&category=$3 [L]
```

I take this rule from my own .htaccess file and just rename variables, so it must work.
If the reason just in this file of course