# .htaccess clean urls from controller/action

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

I use a MVC that would load this url website.com/controller/action by accessing the 'controller' directory and looking for a file called action.php which works great.

No I have some longer urls that I would like to clean, say I have:

```
webiste.com/home/page/parameter1/parameter2
webiste.com/home/page/x/y
webiste.com/home/page/test1/test2
```

So I have a directory called 'home', a file called 'page.php' and the rest are just get parameters.

The question, is there a way to use .htaccess to remove /home/page/ from the url but assume that the controller 'home' and the action 'page.php' still need to be called?

This is my .htaccess file by the way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: How should `parameter1/parameter2` be passed to `page.php`?

Comment: I'm now thinking that this might not be possible with just .htaccess   I will probably have to write some function to take care of this, although I'm not completely sure what it should do.

Comment: this post should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208