# Beautify url with controller and action as query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I am creating a custom PHP MVC pattern from scratch. This is how my url looks like

```
http://domain.com/post/create
```

I could achieve this with the following `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

So, when I print my `$_GET`, I am getting this

```
Array ( [controller] => post [action] => create )
```

Up to this is fine. But my issue is, if I have any extra parameter in query string, I am not able to get that.

ie. if I print `$_GET` for `http://domain.com/post/create?id=1`, I am not getting `id`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need `[QSA, L]` instead of `[L]`

Comment: you also might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly where the `QSA` flag is created for. By default, if you don't specify a query string, it will re-use the query string of the original request. If you specify a query string, it will overwrite it. If you use the `QSA` or `qsappend` (query string append) flag, it will append the original query string to the new query string. See [this documentation document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) for more information.

Your rule would end up looking like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
```