# Request param from url in mvc using htaccess and php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The real url format is

```
http://localhost/myfolder/index.php?url=login/register&step=1
```

After mod rewrite I get

```
http://localhost/myfolder/login/register/step/1
```

All good but how can I get the value of step in a php file.If I do `$_GET['step']` then I get nothing.

My htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews

# turn rewriting on
RewriteEngine On

# When using the script within a sub-folder, put this path here, like /mysubfolder/
# If your app is in the root of your web folder, then please delete this line or comment it out
RewriteBase /mybb/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?url=$0&step=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Show your current rules?

Comment: I have updated the question with added htaccess code.

Comment: @Raj , you probably would find this post useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208

Comment: Thanks @tereško I will have a look in the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(?:/(step)/([0-9]+))?/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: You are just brilliant.Thanks a lot for saving my life.Answer accepted but can't vote up as it says minimum 15 reputation required.Sorry.