# Php MVC dynamic urls

Tags: php, url-routing

I want to know if its possible to create urls dynamically in MVC. 
Example i am building a shopping store in which i have categories and products. Now if i use product before calling category name or product name it works (http://www.example.com/products/mycategory). But i don't want to use products in the center the URL that i require is http://www.example.com/mycategory.

Same this i want for the content pages.

Can any body help me out on this matter.

Comment: You may use some `htaccess` to redirect `http://www.example.com/mycategory` to `http://www.example.com/products/mycategory`

Comment: What framework are you using? You want to set up a controller that allows you to harness that end point.

Comment: I am building my own framework @Darren.
Kamran in MVC you don't need to define links in htaccess because every thing is controling in Controllers

Comment: @WaqarAzeem Just set up a controller called `mycategory` with an `index` method which would allow you to simply access `www.mysite.com/mycategory`

Comment: @Darren thanks for suggetion i will try it

Comment: @WaqarAzeem you might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw it up in an answer here for you. Basically if you're following `MVC` structure and all, your controllers are always your endpoints that are visible to the user.

Sine that is the case, all you want to do is create a new controller that matches the term you want to use.

```
class mycategoryController extends Controller {

    function index() {
        // do your stuff...
    }

}
```

I can't say exactly how you create your controllers, but that will give you the general gist of things.