# MVC pattern implementation

Tags: php, url-routing, autoload

I have my own MVC. 
In my route file I have next code:

```
<?php
class Route
{
    static function run()
    {
        // контроллер и действие по умолчанию
        $controller_name = 'Main';
        $action_name = 'index';

        $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        // получаем имя контроллера
        if ( !empty($routes[1]) )
        {   
            $controller_name = $routes[1];
        }

        // получаем имя экшена
        if ( !empty($routes[2]) )
        {
            $action_name = $routes[2];
        }

        // добавляем префиксы

        $controller_name = 'Controller_'.$controller_name;
        $action_name = 'action_'.$action_name;




        // подцепляем файл с классом контроллера
        $controller_file = strtolower($controller_name).'.php';
        $controller_path = "myapp/controllers/".$controller_file;
        if(file_exists($controller_path))
        {
            include "myapp/controllers/".$controller_file;
        }
        else
        {
            /*
            правильно было бы кинуть здесь исключение,
            но для упрощения сразу сделаем редирект на страницу 404
            */
            Route::ErrorPage404();
        }

        // создаем контроллер
        $controller = new $controller_name;
        $action = $action_name;

        if(method_exists($controller, $action))
        {
            // вызываем действие контроллера
            $controller->$action();
        }
        else
        {
            // здесь также разумнее было бы кинуть исключение
            Route::ErrorPage404();
        }

    }

    function ErrorPage404()
    {
        $host = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        header("Status: 404 Not Found");
        header('Location:'.$host.'404');
    }
}
```

**My core controller has next code:**

```
<?php
class Controller {

    public $model;
    public $view;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = new View();
    }

    function action_index()
    {

    }
}

?>
```

So, I don't know how to write BASE URL, because then I try to go on `http://localhost:81/mymvc/main/index`
it say 404 Not Found page, and in Apache log file I have next:

```
[Wed Nov 26 22:30:29.481678 2014] [:error] [pid 1692:tid 780] [client 127.0.0.1:50310] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Controller_mymvc' not found in C:\\www\\mymvc\\myapp\\base\\route.php on line 49
```

So how can I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using configured htaccess files?

Comment: then I create a controler with $controller = new $controller_name, it takes my base url and subfolder were I placed project. But My controller think that mymvc folder it's somecontroller.

Comment: yes I use htaccess:                                    DirectoryIndex /mymvc/index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Comment: you have to remove leading base url string from request uri, have it in config, and if it's not blank remove it from current uri

Comment: Few notes: learn to use namespaces, `explode()` is a terrible way to route .. try modifying/adapting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208) approach, stop using static methods.