# RewriteRule in MVC php application

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, seo, url-routing

I have a simple MVC application in PHP, all requests are handled by the following code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so if for example i have a url like app.com/profile/view/1

the url param will be "profile/view/1", this is segmented by the app and profile controller will be called, view action from the profile controller will be called, and the id 1 will be passed to the view method.

what i want to do is:

app.com/profile/1/seo-friendly-name-of-profile

but this doesn't work because its trying to find the action "1" in the profile controller.

What should i add to the htaccess file to achieve something like that?

Comment: This has little to do with "mvc" nor the RewriteRule. Since you are using a bland match-all (`.+` instead of separating id and path segments) and a routing scripting, you'll have to adapt your URL path dispatching script.

Comment: are you suggesting that i should add a second rule here? or modify my php script that checks the segments and check if there is a profile keyword and do something else instead of trying to call the method?

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is not .htaccess problem its more a PHP/URL parsing issue
the easy way is to get

```
seo-friendly-name-of-profile
```

part parsed as parameter and handled in your controller 
[This urlParsing code from simple MVC](https://github.com/alexgarrett/simple-mvc/blob/master/app/core/App.php)  should get you started

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, this i quite similar with my code.