# Why cant work roting, when i get id with php7 in db

Tags: php, routes

In my project db connection works, because I can get all info at db and can it record into db. Routs are working too, when I write in adress input a word "/blog", but when I write "/blog/1" or some other numbers it doesn't work.

**class "Router"**

```
<?php

class Router
{
    private $routes;

    public function __construct(){
        $routesPath = ROOT.'/config/routes.php';
        $this->routes = include($routesPath);
    }


    private function getURI(){
        if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        }
    }

    public function run (){

        $uri = $this->getURI();

        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern=>$path) {

            if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {

                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$uriPattern~", $path, $uri);

                $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

                $controllerName = array_shift($segments).'Controller';

                $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

                $actionName = 'action'.ucfirst(array_shift($segments));

                $parameters = $segments;


               $controllerFile = ROOT . '/controllers/' .
                   $controllerName . '.php';

               if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                   include_once ($controllerFile);
               }

               $controllerObject = new $controllerName;
               $result = call_user_func_array(array($controllerObject, $actionName), $parameters);
               if ($result != null) {
                   break;
               }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**class BlogController**

```
<?php

include_once ROOT. '/models/Blog.php';

class BlogController
{

    public function actionIndex() {


        $recordsList = array();
        $recordsList = Blog::getRecordsList();


        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($recordsList);
        echo '</pre>';

        echo '<a href="#">Read more ></a>';

        return true;
    }

    public function actionView($id){

        if($id) {
            $recordsItem = Blog::getRecordsItemById($id);

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($recordsItem);
            echo '</pre>';

        }

        echo '<a href="#">< Back </a>';

        return true;
    }
}
```

**class model 'Blog'**

```
<?php
class Blog
{


    public static function getRecordsItemById($id){
        $id =  intval($id);

        if ($id) {

            $db = Database::getConnection();

            $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `blog_records` WHERE `id` ='.$id);
           $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

           $recordsItem = $result->fetch();

           return $recordsItem;

            return $result;
        }
    }

    public static function getRecordsList() {
        $db = Database::getConnection();

        $recordsList=array();
        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `blog_records`'
            . 'ORDER BY reg_date DESC');

        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $recordsList[$i] ['id'] = $row['id'];
            $recordsList[$i] ['name'] = $row['name'];
            $recordsList[$i] ['content'] = $row['content'];
            $recordsList[$i] ['reg_date'] = $row['reg_date'];
            $i++;
        }

        return $recordsList;

    }

}
```

Comment: I write in php7

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208