# PHP : getting complete url with hashtag

Tags: php

i am trying to get complete php url.My url is

```
http://localhost/site/allproducts.php#oral
```

i can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to get uri first part but `#oral` is not working

my question is how do i get this part of the url

Comment: You can't. It's not getting sent to the server.

Comment: so is there any way out to do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby

Comment: @Sikander it depends. You can use JS to transform that URL, but it wont work with direct links. Instead I would recommend using "pushstate" (so that your link actually says `http://localhost/site/allproducts/oral`. Also, I suspect a big part of the problem is that you don't know how to do routing in PHP. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208) is helpful for you.