# Retrieve parameter from URL php

Tags: php, content-management-system, url-routing

I'm having this PHP MVC Application that I'm trying to implement. 
My attempt here is to add/edit/delete CATEGORIES. A category has a name and a description. It's view is basically a table with categories data and a link for edit/delete.

I've loaded dynamically and finished the add Category part, but I'm stuck at edit/delete.

My routing is set up like this: Controller/Action/Parameter.

Click EDIT link, application grabs the ID of the row and proceeds to edit page, so : /categories/edit/(categoryID) 
 So if I wish to edit the first entry entry, it'll go to categories/edit/1

My question is: how to I retrieve the category ID? That 1 from the URL.

$_GET['id'] does not work as my routing doesn't look like categories/edit.php?id=etc

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// get controller name
if (isset($routes[1]) && !empty($routes[1])) {
    $controllerName = $routes[1];
}

// get name action
if (isset($routes[2]) && !empty($routes[2])) {
    $actionName = $routes[2];
}

if (isset($routes[3]) && !empty($routes[3])) {
    $param = $routes[3];
}
```

Apologies. Here's the route.php.
Also, using array_pop to grab the id does not appear to work.

Comment: What are you getting `print_r($_REQUEST)`

Comment: show us maybe some code and your link looks like a REST API (maybe search also about that)

Comment: post your routing rule, that will give the clear idea of what 1 is being passed in.

Comment: Are you using some kind of routing library like FastRoute? I believe that one uses regular expressions.

Comment: You mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use something like this,

```
    // Get the current URL
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // Explode with /
    $parts = explode('/', rtrim($url, '/'));

    // Pop the element in the end of the array
    $id = array_pop($parts);
```