# I am not able to get the right pathname for directory,can anyone help me to tell me how to find th pathname?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

[image]

I am new to mvc,I am currently building my on mvc and m finding some difficulties in building it.I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error:  *Class 'userscontroller' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc1\app\core\app.php:20 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc1\public\index.php(4): app->__construct() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc1\app\core\app.php on line 20*

If you need anyother code of mvc included in my directories,you are free ask :)

Please help me to resolve the error I have made in the following code:

app.php   [Click here to see the image containing my directory files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hFOd.png)

```
    <?php
    class app{


        protected $controller ='userscontroller';
        protected $method ='users';
        protected $params =[];


        function __construct()
        {

        $url =$this->url();

             if(file_exists('../app/controllers/'.$url[0].'.php')){
                $this->controller = $url[0];
                unset($url[0]);
                }
            require_once '../app/controllers/'.$this->controller .'.php';
            $this->controller = new $this->controller;


            if(isset($url[1])){
            if (method_exists($this->controller,$url[1])){
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
                }
      }
       $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) :[];
       call_user_func_array([$this->controller,$this->method],$this->params);

       }

      function url(){
      if(isset($_GET['url'])){
  return  explode('/',filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url','     /'),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));   


  }

  }
  }
      ?>





    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEPhW.png
```

Comment: Don't you think it is still insecure to directly initialize a class depending on the user input? If you someday forget and put a class that contains exploitable code in ../app/controllers, it will call the constructor and do something you don't expect it to do.

Comment: Yes I know its insecure but currently I only want to run  this code anyhow.

Comment: Try outputting the path to the file and stop the execution with die() and check if the path is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this disaster, use an autoloader.

For a basic example you can try adopting this: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

But if you are lazy, a much better approach would be to use the autoloader, that comes with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) (which you should be already using). The exact details of using that autoloader are explained here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

You also should probably read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208), since you current approach to routing is somewhat ... emm ... not good.

As for your path issue, it would probably go away, if you started using
absolute paths: `include __DIR__ . '/../something/file.php';`

**P.S.** IMHO, the use of `include_once` and `require_once` can be considered a code smell.