# PHP - Routing not working in subfolder sites

Tags: php, url-rewriting, frameworks, url-routing

I am trying to create a php project. At the time of routing the url routing works perfect with virtualhost domain. But the functionality doesn't work properly when I placed my project inside a subfolder. My Router Class looks like

```
 class Router{
    private $request;
    public function __construct($request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function get($route, $file){
        $uri = trim( $this->request, "/" );
        $uri = explode("/", $uri);
        if (empty($uri[0])) {
            $file['platform'] = '';
            $file['controller'] = 'Index';
            $file['action'] = 'index';
        }
        if($uri[0] == trim($route, "/")){
            define("PLATFORM", isset($file['platform']) ? $file['platform'] : '');
            define("CONTROLLER", isset($file['controller']) ? $file['controller'] : 'Index');
            define("ACTION", isset($file['action']) ? $file['action'] : 'index');
            $plarform = !empty(PLATFORM)? PLATFORM . DS: '';
            define("CURRENT_CONTROLLER", CONTROLLER_PATH . $plarform);
            define("CURRENT_VIEW", VIEW_PATH . PLATFORM . DS);
        }
    }
}
```

And initialize the function like

```
require CORE_PATH.'Router.php';
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$router = new Router($request);
```

But the same work in

`http://www.mysite.local`, `http://www.mysite.local/about`, `http://www.mysite.local/contact`

which is a virtualhost.

But When I call something like

`http://localhost/mysite/`, `http://localhost/mysite/about`, `http://localhost/mysite/contact`

it doesn't work as I expect. Please suggest me any idea to working on this.

My `.htaccess` as like below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have already tried with

`RewriteBase /mysite`

Comment: Why are you not using virtual host for that? Also, you should use regexp-based router, kinda how it's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208

Comment: @tereško I developed with virtualhost. But When I take a look within a folder. The functionality breaks and its because the foldername take as controllername. I found a solution as the below. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya Finally I got a solution after working on it.
I just changed `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to `$SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`.

There is an `index.php` in the `$SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`.
That is if URL is `http://www.mysite.local/about` actual `PHP_SELF` is

```
http://www.mysite.local/index.php/about
```

Same as in

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php/about
```

So I Just explode the siteurl with `index.php` as below.

```
    require CORE_PATH.'Router.php';
    $request = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $requesturi = explode('index.php', $request);
    unset($requesturi[0]);
    $request = implode($requesturi);
    $router = new Router($request);
```