# Matching Url with fnmatch and Patterns

Tags: php, url

I want to match the Following URLS to

> http://deploy.local/user/12  => fnmatch(**PATTERN???**, $url);
>   http://deploy.local/user/tree => fnmatch(**PATTERN???**, $url);

But

```
fnmatch("user/[0-9]+" , $url);
```

does not work with these..

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Use `preg_match()` .. maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19309893/727208) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you meant by matching, you meant matching the whole URL, then the following regular expression should do the trick:

```
^https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\/user\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

I also made you a permalink at rubular, containing the regex:

http://rubular.com/r/g27NI0bHfI